# Gradient appears banded in a SurfaceView, but looks very smooth in a normal View

Tags: android, surfaceview

My problem is that when drawing a simple test image (a rectangle with a gradient fill) within a `SurfaceView`, the gradient has colour banding. When drawing exactly the same rectangle with the same gradient in a simple extended `View`, the gradient looks very smooth, and as nice as I would expect for 32-bit colour.

This is occurring side by side using the test `SurfaceView` placed alongside the test `View` within the same layout in the same `Activity`.

For information, in the `Activity` class I am calling `window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888)` to switch the Activity to 32-bit colour, as this was the solution in the past to eliminate banding in gradients (however, I believe that this is no longer necessary at a certain Android level, where 32-bit is the default). My `minSdkVersion` is 8.

The test code that appears in the `onDraw()` of both the simple extended `View` and the `SurfaceView` is:

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setAntiAlias(false);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(false);
    paint.setDither(false); 
    Shader shader = new LinearGradient(
            0,
            0,
            0,
            200,
            new int[]{0xff150d2f,0xff432b96},
            null,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
            );

    paint.setShader(shader);    
    canvas.drawRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(), paint);
```

Here is the screenshot showing the `SurfaceView` above and the normal `View` beneath. I realise that the banding is very subtle in this example; it's even more apparent when the gradient sweeps over a smaller band of colours.

[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions, please?

Trev

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution myself in the end by adding this into the `SurfaceView`'s constructor:

```
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```