# Android color profile?

Tags: android, colors, photoshop

I've noticed that colors in Photoshop and on my Android HTC Desire S are very different.

Picture on Android looks a bit ugly.

I'm using numerical color values that I get from Photoshop image using Eyedropper tool.

What can I do to help this? Halp.

Current photoshop profile is sRGB. Windows screen profile is sRGB calibrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the Android Design Preview tool to screen share my canvas from Photoshop directly to the device I'm developing for. This way I can see exactly how my design looks on the device.

The tool lives here: http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/

Comment: Update: I found this great little app that uses the Remote Connection feature in PS to mirror a canvas to your device(s). Very handy, and simple. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.markushi.pixl

Comment: Yup ^ I use this now.

Answer (score 0):

It would be worth showing us exactly how you're rendering your graphics in your Android application. In other words, where and how are you using this colour. In Android, a very frequent issue you can come up against is the fact that image bitmaps, and bitmaps that back `Canvas`es, can be configured for various colour depths, and aren't necessarily 32-bit (RGBA_8888) by default. If you're taking a 32-bit colour (including alpha) value from Photoshop and using it to draw on a bitmap that's not set for RGBA_8888 for instance, then you will have truncation of the colour value and the colour representation won't be quite as you expected.

Comment: I'm aware of the RGBA_8888. I'm drawing a simple gradient and it's colors do not really match my PC screen. It's a color profile problem, I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: OK. I must confess I've no experience of colour *profiles* on Android devices, but I have run into colour depth problems many times, and a current application I'm working on has required a number of measures to ensure that various `Views` and `SurfaceViews` are truly working in RGBA_8888 to ensure that colours are as they should be, and to avoid nasty banding in gradients. If you're confident that this isn't your issue then fine, but I raised this as a possible solution because there's no code or specific information in your question to rule out a colour depth problem.

Comment: Just to place further emphasis, if your target platform is - I *think* - below 2.2, then you need `window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888)` in the `Activity` to ensure 32-bit depth. Also, if using a `SurfaceView`, check out my own Q&A where I had to implement a further measure to ensure 32-bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774867/gradient-appears-banded-in-a-surfaceview-but-looks-very-smooth-in-a-normal-view/7780026#7780026. This is why I recommend you post example code, your target API and a screenshot, because when you say "very different" and "ugly", it suggests a depth problem.