# Confused about the Gradient Display different in Nexus 7 ( 2012 Model) and Other phones

Tags: android

This is my Gradient drawable xml file  and expected output for nexus 7 but the gradient is not correct ( Linings between shades )!

It look like this

[image]

Correct Output is in phone.

[image]

Is there any pixel format definition?

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#00a484"
    android:startColor="#00407e"
    android:type="linear" />

 </shape>
```

Comment: attach the correct gradient also

Comment: What's wrong in that image that you don't want-  it looks right to me?  If that's the right one, then what happens in the wrong one?

Comment: this is the correct one...

Comment: @GabeSechan Now you can see the image.

Comment: Nexus 7 displays me the wrong Gradient that I am not able to understand.

Comment: I can't give you a good answer, but this has been discussed before here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994129/color-banding-and-artifacts-with-gradients-despite-using-rgba-8888-everywhere.  I'll keep this question open rather than closing it as a dupe though, I think this question deserves a better answer.